# Can you get VMware Server 1.0.x to work?

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, vmware, vmware-server

I'm trying to install [VMware Server 1.0.10](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_server/1_0) (released 2009-10-26) on Ubuntu 10.04.

<sup>(Why not 2.0? Well, I've tried 2.0; didn't like its UI and had some other issues with it too, and I *know* 1.0.x does everything I need.)</sup>

When I run `sudo ./vmware-install.pl`, it fails thusly:

```
None of the pre-built vmmon modules for VMware Server is suitable for your 
running kernel.  Do you want this program to try to build the vmmon module for 
your system (you need to have a C compiler installed on your system)? [yes] 

Using compiler "/usr/bin/gcc". Use environment variable CC to override.

What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running
kernel? [/lib/modules/2.6.32-24-generic/build/include] 

Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.

Building the vmmon module.

Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-24-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:25,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:48:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:104:7: warning: "__FreeBSD__" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/x86.h:20,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/machine.h:24,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:15,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/x86apic.h:79:1: warning: "APIC_BASE_MSR" redefined
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/apic.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/smp.h:13,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/mmzone_64.h:12,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/mmzone.h:4,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:783,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:4,
                 from include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:12:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/apicdef.h:136:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/x86.h:21,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/machine.h:24,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:15,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/x86desc.h:593:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/machine.h:24,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:15,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/x86.h:830:1: warning: "PTE_PFN_MASK" redefined
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:60,
                 from include/linux/irqflags.h:57,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:17,
                 from include/linux/prefetch.h:14,
                 from include/linux/list.h:6,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:12:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:182:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vcpuset.h:78,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:22,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:18,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:16,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:226:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:230:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:298:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:304:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
[...]
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1454:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1587:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:20,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/compat_wait.h:37:5: warning: "VMW_HAVE_EPOLL" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/compat_wait.h:43:5: warning: "VMW_HAVE_EPOLL" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:20,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/compat_wait.h:60: error: conflicting types for ‘poll_initwait’
include/linux/poll.h:70: note: previous declaration of ‘poll_initwait’ was here
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:23,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:28,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:52:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:430:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:676:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:716:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:28,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:52:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:40:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/vmhost.h:13,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:71:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/./include/compat_semaphore.h:5:27: error: asm/semaphore.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:146: error: unknown field ‘nopage’ specified in initializer
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:147: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:150: error: unknown field ‘nopage’ specified in initializer
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:151: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1650: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘euid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1650: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘uid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1651: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘fsuid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1651: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘uid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1652: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘egid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1652: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘gid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1653: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘fsgid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1653: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘gid’
/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1670: error: too many arguments to function ‘smp_call_function’
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-config0/vmmon-only'
Unable to build the vmmon module.

For more information on how to troubleshoot module-related problems, please 
visit our Web site at "http://www.vmware.com/download/modules/modules.html" and
"http://www.vmware.com/support/reference/linux/prebuilt_modules_linux.html".

Execution aborted.
```

**Am I missing some required kernel header packages, or is there something else I can do to fix this?** Or does someone know already that you just can't get these pieces of software to work together?

#### Update

[Turns out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8285/can-you-get-vmware-server-1-0-x-to-work-on-64-bit-ubuntu-10-04/8297#8297) that to get VMware Server 1.0.x working, compiling the kernel module isn't enough, but I'd need to compile my own kernel. While that's certainly doable, for this particular need I think that's a bit too much work.

Comment: Update: I have since switched from (any version of) VMware Server to **VirtualBox** [for my virtualisation needs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43365/creating-running-windows-virtual-machines), and can recommend the same to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain words, these old version of VMWare doesn't work with modern kernels. You can modify de interface source and recompile it following [hhlp link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8285/can-you-get-vmware-server-1-0-x-to-work-on-64-bit-ubuntu-10-04/8291#8291), but it's not for the faint of heart.

In more technical words:

The main problem is that older version of vmware is looking for asm/semaphore.h, a system that is deprecated. Now the kernel uses linux/semaphore.h. There is a patch in the VMWare site to go around this issue, but you will need to make some manual changes to the source even after applying that patch to be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. I'll see tomorrow how much hassle it proves to be to tackle this with hhlp's instructions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9481881&postcount=4) now (running "vmware-update-2.6.31-5.5.9" and editing vmci_kernel_defs.h) but still get the error. Only then I noticed the "NOTE 3" at the end of that post. So there's no other way to do this than by compiling your own kernel? (I've done plenty of that in the past, but right now that might be more work than what I want to invest just to get VMware working...)

Comment: I'm afraid yes. Worse, each day with new kernel changes things are going to get more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

follow this tutorial :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1493522