# Creating a high performance desktop VM hub

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

So, I'm currently running Windows 7, i like linux very much but i can't give up windows programs and games. I can't dualboot, i tried multiple times but i can't be bothered to reboot like, ever and just end up running windows anyways.
But i finally decided what i want to do! I would like to install linux or bsd as my main os and use a vm to run all my windows stuff. As i said i like to game but i also use hardware acceleration in graphics design aplications so i would need a GPU passthrough.
I have a 4790k, gtx970, 16 gb ram and an ssd and would like to keep the performance as close to native as possible.

What distro should i use?
What virtualization software?
Is it possible to passthrough a GPU to multiple VMs running diferent OS's(not at once)? 
Can i mount encrypted partition to a VM?
How would one go about doing this?
What about a Windows licence in a VM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating & running Windows virtual machines?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43365/creating-running-windows-virtual-machines)

Comment: Not really, he's really driving at trying to game in a VM Windows environment.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. They want to give the VM OS full, unshared control over one of the GPUs to get native speeds from that GPU, which isn't yet a simple matter of creating a VM.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex The link you posted is really interesting. I'll see if I can't get this working on my machine at home. I didn't know this was possible yet.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on AskUbuntu but this seems to fit your requirements: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/